# Where can I find more Grindcore Minks?

Tags: the-world-ends-with-you

I have access to all Chapters and all Days, even "Secret".  Where can I find more Grindcore Minks (aka Noise No 22) to fill out my Noise dairy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Noise is one of those optional bosses (Blue Noise).

Select Joshua, Day 6. Walk from the Scramble Crossing (the starting point of this day), head to Center Street Entrance, then go to AMX. Scan this area and you should see a Blue Noise.

This Noise drops the [Mink](http://twewy.wikia.com/wiki/Pin_289) pin only on Hard.

The Grindcore Minks share an HP bar between them and are weak against melee attacks (Positive [Psychs](http://twewy.wikia.com/wiki/Psych)).

Comment: The location is correct, but this noise drops Tektite on Ultimate. (On my DS version, anyway.)

Comment: Updated my answer. I can confirm that Tektite drops from Ultimate on the iOS version, too.